# How to wrap an element with another element with a class [Plain Javascript]?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to wrap a table within a div. I also want the created element to have a class or style. Can anyone here help me achieve that?

```
function wrap(el, wrapper) {
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
  wrapper.appendChild(el);
}

wrap(document.querySelector("table"), document.createElement("div"));
```

Comment: Put `function wrap(el, wrapper)` before the `{`...

Comment: ooh sorry. I mean I want the created element (div) to have a style or class.

Comment: `wrapper.classList.add(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [`classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) like the following:

```
function wrap(el, wrapper) {
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
  wrapper.classList.add("wrapper");
  wrapper.appendChild(el);
}
```

```js
function wrap(el, wrapper) {
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
  wrapper.classList.add("wrapper");
  wrapper.appendChild(el);
}

wrap(document.querySelector("table"), document.createElement("div"));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```